# Finding an explicit formula for the projection on a subspace of $\ell^2$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, projection

Consider $\ell^2(\Bbb C)=\{x=(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}|\, \sum_{n\ge 1}|x_n|^2<+\infty\}$ endowed with the usual inner product and the subspace $V:=\{x=(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}\in \ell^2 |\, x_1=2x_2-x_3\}$. Find an explicit formula for the projection on $V$.

**My attempt**

First of all, I considered the map $f:\ell^2\to \Bbb C$ defined by $f(x)=x_1-2x_2+x_3$, since it's continuous, then $V=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a closed set.
Given $x=(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$, we have $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(2x_2-x_3,x_2,\dots)=(2x_2,x_2,\dots)-(x_3,0,\dots)$, I tried to use this property of the elements of $V$ to have more information about the inner product:
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{n\ge 1} x_n \overline{y_n}=2x_2\overline{y_1}+x_2 \overline{y_2}+\dots -x_3 y_1 $$
Other than that, I've no idea on how to find an explicit formula for the projection.

Note that here I'm using the convention $\Bbb N=\{1,2,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subspace can be described as $V=v^\perp$ where $v=(1,-2,1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots).$ In general the orthogonal projection on $V=v^\perp$ is given by $$Px=x-{\langle x,v\rangle\over \langle v,v\rangle}\,v$$ So in the OP case we get $$Px=x-{1\over 6}(x_1-2x_2+x_3)\,v$$

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm doing a similar ex, here the space is $V=\{x=(x_n) | x_{2n}=x_{2n-1}\}$. I followed your method and found that $V=v^{\perp}$ where $v=(1,-1,1,-1,\dots)$, but I can find the projection of $(1/n)_{n\ge 1}$ on $V$ since the norm of $v$ is not finite. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The space $V$ consists of elements  orthogonal to $e_{2n-1}-e_{2n}$ for every $n,$ where $\{e_k\}$ denotes the standard basis in $\ell^2.$ The projection of $x$ onto $V$ is equal $y$ where $y_{2n-1}=y_{2n}={1\over 2}(x_{2n-1}+x_{2n})$ for every $n.$